# ng-repeat store separate values

Tags: angularjs, cookies, angularjs-ng-repeat, voting

I want to store the users vote's inside a cookie, the problem is that inside the ng-repeat I have a value called session.upVoteCount. But it is supposed to be a separate value for each event list item. Is it possible to store each upVoteCount separately and then retrieve them separately again?

```
<li ng-repeat="session in event.sessions | filter:query | orderBy:sortorder" class="span11">
                <div class="row session">
                    <div class="col-sm-1 well votingWidget">
                        <div class="votingButton" ng-click="upVoteSession(session)">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="badge badge-inverse">
                            <div>{{session.upVoteCount}}</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="votingButton" ng-click="downVoteSession(session)">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </li>
```

and in my controller I have this:

```
$scope.upVoteSession = function(session) {
        session.upVoteCount++;            
    };

$scope.downVoteSession = function(session) {
        session.upVoteCount--;   
    };
```

Comment: are you getting errors? please provide a jsfiddle(http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 0):

First, I don't recommend to use term 'session', but 'votes'. However, it's your call.

I simplify your problem in this example

http://plnkr.co/edit/l7tQRbuOtEDJetY5eTsf?p=preview

Javascript:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.votes = {};
  $scope.vote = function(key, val) {
    $scope.votes[key] = $scope.votes[key] || 0;
    $scope.votes[key]+= val;            
  };
}
```

Html:

```
<li ng-repeat="no in [1,2,3,4,5]">
  {{no}} : {{votes[no]}} <br/>
  <a href="" ng-click="vote(no, +1)">upvote</a>
  <a href="" ng-click="vote(no, -1)">downvote</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys I solved it myself, I could not get it to work with JSfiddle so I have uploaded the entire thing. Click on server.bat and browser to localhost:8000/eventdetails.html and you will see it working.

https://mega.co.nz/#!1d9yiYiA!zTzdztLAmhVDVYOvvVLINETI2bo_WjxCBteWYm2VUKc

controller:

```
eventsApp.controller('EventController',
    function EventController($scope, $cookieStore, eventData) {
        $scope.sortorder = 'name';
        var ape = eventData.getEvent();
        ape.then(function (banana) {
            $scope.event = banana;
            angular.forEach(banana.sessions, function (value, key) {
                var storecookie = ($cookieStore.get(value.name));
                if (typeof storecookie !== "undefined") {
                    value.upVoteCount = storecookie;
                }
            });
        });
        $scope.upVoteSession = function (session) {
            session.upVoteCount++;
            $cookieStore.put(session.name, session.upVoteCount);
        };

        $scope.downVoteSession = function (session) {
            session.upVoteCount--;
            $cookieStore.put(session.name, session.upVoteCount);
        };
    }
);
```